# wpdb->insert multiple record at once

Tags: database, mysql, wpdb

So after I have created the table 'settings-table' i want to add a couple of records to it.

This is how I want to do it, not the best way, so I need a better way to do this because I will add more records to the table.

EXAMPLE 1

```
 $wpdb->insert('settings-table', array('option_name'   => 'name-1', 
                                       'option_value'  => 'val-1', 
                                       'option_created'=> current_time('mysql'),
                                       'option_edit'   => current_time('mysql'),
                                       'option_user'   => 'user-1' 
                                       ));    
 $wpdb->insert('settings-table', array('option_name'   => 'name-2', 
                                       'option_value'  => 'val-2', 
                                       'option_created'=> current_time('mysql'),
                                       'option_edit'   => current_time('mysql'),
                                       'option_user'   => 'user-2' 
                                       ));
 $wpdb->insert('settings-table', array('option_name'   => 'name-1', 
                                       'option_value'  => 'val-3', 
                                       'option_created'=> current_time('mysql'),
                                       'option_edit'   => current_time('mysql'),
                                       'option_user'   => 'user-3'
```

UPDATE

this works(any other better solutions are welcome)

```
$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO settings-table
            (`option_name`, `option_value`, `option_created`, `option_edit`, `option_user`)
            VALUES
            ('name-1', 'val-1', current_time('mysql'), current_time('mysql'), 'user-1'),
            ('name-2', 'val-2', current_time('mysql'), current_time('mysql'), 'user-2'),
            ('name-3', 'val-3',  current_time('mysql'), current_time('mysql'), 'user-3')")
```

Comment: What are these settings for? You should consider using the `options` table (with all of the WP functionality that exists for it), or `postmeta` or `usermeta` (again, with all the WP functionality that already exists around them).  **Finally**: if you want to use your own table, a loop would probably give you what you want, but we'd to have more context, understand what it is you're trying to accomplish "big picture"

Comment: The example above is just an example, I dont want to use the wp-options table. I cant give anymore info as there is none, it very basic, I just need to add multiple records inside the table.

Comment: your use of `prepare` is incorrect, which would probably generate a warning. [see the codex for the correct format](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks).

Comment: Yes I have seen it, I have changed it, but I still need a way to add multiple records to the table

Comment: You can give more information.  What kind of records are you inserting? How are the records being generated?  Again, a loop would probably get you what you need, but without more context, it's hard to provide a useful answer.  FYI, you *could* use a simple `$wpdb->query()` with a manually constructed set of insert values to insert multiple rows at once...

Comment: I have solved it by using the $wpdb->query().

Answer (score 10):

```
$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO settings-table
            (option_name, option_value, option_created, option_edit, option_user)
            VALUES
            ('name-1', 'val-1', current_time('mysql'), current_time('mysql'), 'user-1'),
            ('name-2', 'val-2', current_time('mysql'), current_time('mysql'), 'user-2'),
            ('name-3', 'val-3',  current_time('mysql'), current_time('mysql'), 'user-3')")
```

In the query which you had posted, the column names shouldn't be  in string.

Answer (score 5):

**$wpdb->insert** function doesn't support multiple records to be inserted into single function call. You have to loop over your data and prepare the data to be inserted and then use $wpdb->insert into a loop and insert records one by one.

Instead, we can prepare insert query as follow and run a query only once.

So, if we want to insert **100** records, we need to run **100 insert queries** if we want to use **$wpdb->insert**. And if we use following code, we need to run only **1 insert query**.

Hope that helps.

```
function do_insert($place_holders, $values) {

    global $wpdb;

    $query           = "INSERT INTO settings-table (`option_name`, `option_value`, `option_created`, `option_edit`, `option_user`) VALUES ";
    $query           .= implode( ', ', $place_holders );
    $sql             = $wpdb->prepare( "$query ", $values );

    if ( $wpdb->query( $sql ) ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

$data_to_be_inserted = array( array(
    'option_name'   => 'name-1', 
    'option_value'  => 'val-1', 
    'option_created'=> current_time('mysql'),
    'option_edit'   => current_time('mysql'),
    'option_user'   => 'user-1' 
),

array(
    'option_name'   => 'name-2', 
    'option_value'  => 'val-2', 
    'option_created'=> current_time('mysql'),
    'option_edit'   => current_time('mysql'),
    'option_user'   => 'user-2' 
),
array(
    'option_name'   => 'name-1', 
    'option_value'  => 'val-3', 
    'option_created'=> current_time('mysql'),
    'option_edit'   => current_time('mysql'),
    'option_user'   => 'user-3'
));

$values = $place_holders = array();

if(count($data_to_be_inserted) > 0) {
    foreach($data_to_be_inserted as $data) {
        array_push( $values, $data['option_name'], $data['option_value'], $data['option_created'], $data['option_edit'], $data['option_user']);
        $place_holders[] = "( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)";
    }

    do_insert( $place_holders, $values );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I came up with this solution that extends the `wpdb` class so that it uses it's internal data processing functions:

```php
<?php
class wpdbx extends wpdb {
  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
  }

  public function insert_multiple($table, $data, $format = null) {
    $this->insert_id = 0;

    $formats = array();
    $values = array();

    foreach ($data as $index => $row) {
      $row = $this->process_fields($table, $row, $format);
      $row_formats = array();

      if ($row === false || array_keys($data[$index]) !== array_keys($data[0])) {
        continue;
      }

      foreach($row as $col => $value) {
        if (is_null($value['value'])) {
          $row_formats[] = 'NULL';
        } else {
          $row_formats[] = $value['format'];
        }

        $values[] = $value['value'];
      }

      $formats[] = '(' . implode(', ', $row_formats) . ')';
    }

    $fields  = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($data[0])) . '`';
    $formats = implode(', ', $formats);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `$table` ($fields) VALUES $formats";

    $this->check_current_query = false;
    return $this->query($this->prepare($sql, $values));
  }
}

global $wpdbx;
$wpdbx = new wpdbx();
?>
```

You can then use it like this:

```php
<?php
global $wpdbx;
$results = $wpdbx->insert_multiple(
  'settings-table',
  array(
    array(
      'option_name'   => 'name-1', 
      'option_value'  => 'val-1', 
      'option_created'=> current_time('mysql'),
      'option_edit'   => current_time('mysql'),
      'option_user'   => 'user-1' 
    ),
    array(
      'option_name'   => 'name-2', 
      'option_value'  => 'val-2', 
      'option_created'=> current_time('mysql'),
      'option_edit'   => current_time('mysql'),
      'option_user'   => 'user-2' 
    ),
    array(
      'option_name'   => 'name-1', 
      'option_value'  => 'val-3', 
      'option_created'=> current_time('mysql'),
      'option_edit'   => current_time('mysql'),
      'option_user'   => 'user-3'
    )
  )
);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This Will Also Work

```
        $nameArray = array("name-1", "name-2", "name-3");
        $valueArray = array("val-1", "val-2" , "val-3");
        $userArray = array("user-1" , "user-2", "user-3");
        $maxRow= count($nameArray); // can use count of any array
        $setting_values = array();
        $time = current_time('mysql');

        for($x=0;$x<$maxRow; $x++){
            $SettingContext = [
                'option_name' => "'" . $nameArray[$x] . "'",
                'option_value' => "'" . $valueArray[$x] . "'",
                'option_created' => "'" . $time . "'",
                'option_edit' => "'" . $time . "'",
                'option_user' => "'" . $userArray[$x] . "'"
            ];
            $setting_values[] = "(" . implode(',', $SettingContext) . ")";
        }
        $settingSubmit = implode(',', $setting_values);
        $setting_save = $wpdb->query("
                INSERT INTO setting
                (option_name, option_value, option_created,option_edit, option_user)
                VALUES " . $settingSubmit
        );
```